# Testing ASP.NET 5 with Entity Framework 7 using in memory database

Tags: testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am wanting to get ahold of the Context that I am injecting into the controllers during testing and modify the data in the "in memory" version of the database context.

So the controller looks like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly TestContext _testContext;
    public TestController(TestContext testContext)
    {
        _testContext = testContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new { _testContext.Users });
    }
}
```

The test looks like this

```
public class SiteTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetIt()
    {
        var server = TestServer.Create(app => { app.UseMvc(); }, services =>
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<TestContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase());

            services.AddScoped<TestContext, TestContext>();
        });

        var client = server.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/test");
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Assert.True(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }
}
```

I would love to somehow get ahold of the context before the client gets the request and modify what data will be coming back from the database context.

I have the test [project](https://github.com/CraigSelbert/ASP5_EF7_Test) in GitHub

Comment: Try to use some Moqing library, something like https://github.com/Moq/moq4. Just find the one that works with vNext project.

Comment: @Alkasai what I am wanting is to get ahold of the in memory database being the mock and load it with data.

Comment: @CraigSelbert Have you managed to find a solution to this? I have the same problem where I want to get a hold of the DbContext or the application's IServiceProvider to be able to seed some test data

Comment: @Vasea - Here was the solution Microsoft provided.  https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/519

Comment: Here is some solution for you. http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/unit-testing-aspnet5-entityframework7-inmemory-database Guess it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting .NET Core, you won't be able to make use of any automatic mocking frameworks.

The best you can do is make all your methods in `TestContext` virtual, then extend it in your unit tests.

```
public class IntegrationTestContext : TestContext
{
    // override methods here
}
```

You can then use

```
var context = new IntegrationTestContext();
services.AddInstance<TestContext>(context);
```

You can also capture any extra information you want in `IntegrationTestContext` and access it from within your test.